# How to add Material-ui App Bar to class component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui

Im trying to add the App Bar from Material-ui (https://material-ui.com/demos/app-bar/) to my NavBar component. Material-ui examples creates a function and exports it.

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <NavBar />
  </div>
);
}
}
```

The NavBar component should return the App Bar from the Material example.

```
class NavBar extends Component {

render() {
    return (
        //App Bar from material.
    )
}
}

export default NavBar;
```

So far I have tried to create the const and use it in the navbar component render()

```
const styles = {
root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
},
grow: {
    flexGrow: 1,
},
menuButton: {
    marginLeft: -12,
    marginRight: 20,
},
};
```

class NavBar extends Component {

```
render() {
    return (
        <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton className={styles.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" className={styles.grow}>
            News
          </Typography>
          <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    )
}
}
```

But it doesn't render like the example one, for example the login button position its beside the News label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you wrapping your `NavBar` component in the `withStyles` HOC as in the Material example? It looks like you are trying to use the `styles` object directly in `className` which will not work as you expect. You have to pass the styles into your `NavBar` component using `withStyles` like:

```
export default withStyles(styles)(NavBar);
```

Then access the styles in your `NavBar` from the `classes` prop:

```
render() {
  const { classes } = this.props;
  return (
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Toolbar>
        <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
          <MenuIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" className={classes.grow}>
          News
        </Typography>
        <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
```

The `withStyles` HOC registers your `styles` object as CSS and passes the class names into the wrapped component (in this case `NavBar`) so that you can use them in the render function. You can find more information about `withStyles` in Material-UI [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#withstyles-styles---options----higher-order-component).

Comment: thanks a lot! Also thanks for the information about withStyles, checking it now!